# Как передать аргумент COLOR из функции конвертированный в 0x?

Tags: python, discord

нужен способ решения задачи.

На вход мы получаем команду со следующими аргументами:

```
async def create_family(inter, familyname, colour, leader: disnake.Member):
```

В colour поступает HTML код цвета, который нужно конвертировать с помощью 0x.
Пример: на вход получаем AEEEEEE, на выходе должно получится 0xAEEEEE, пытался сделать так:

```
familyrole = await guild.create_role(name=familyname, colour=f'0x{colour}')
```

Не вышло.
Попробовал по другому:

```
sep = 0x
colourforsep = colour
sep.join(colourforsep)
```

Не получилось, выдает ошибку в строке familyrole = await guild.create_role(name=familyname, colour=f'0x{colour}')

disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'

Помогите решить!!!

Пробовал решение пользователя из комментариев:

```
class Families:
    def str_to_hex(myStr):
        base16INT = int(myStr, 16)
        hex_value = hex(base16INT)
        return hex_value

    @bot.slash_command()
    async def create_family(inter, familyname, colour, leader: disnake.Member):
        for role in inter.author.roles:
            if role.id in high_perms:
                guild = inter.guild
                familyid = uuid.uuid4()
                availableColor = str_to_hex(colour)
                familyrole = await guild.create_role(name=familyname, colour=disnake.Colour(availableColor))
```

Comment: `colour=discord.Colour(f'0x{colour}')` а если так ?

Comment: disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Expected int parameter, received str instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то туда надо передать `hex`. Написал небольшую функция перевода строки в hex. Попробуйте так

```
def str_to_hex(myStr):
    base16INT = int(myStr, 16)
    hex_value = hex(base16INT)
    return int(hex_value,0)

async def create_family(inter, familyname, colour, leader: disnake.Member):
    .......
    availableColour = str_to_hex(colour)
    familyrole = await guild.create_role(name=familyname, colour=discord.Colour(availableColour))
```

Comment: Можно полностью, как его сюда вставтиь?

Comment: что полностью? я же написал как вставить `colour=discord.Colour(str_to_hex(colour))`

Comment: @bot.slash_command()
    async def create_family(inter, familyname, colour, leader: disnake.Member):
        for role in inter.author.roles:
            if role.id in high_perms:
                guild = inter.guild
                familyid = uuid.uuid4()
                familyrole = await guild.create_role(name=familyname, colour=disnake.Colour(f'0x{colour}'))

Comment: Функция автоматически получит colour ?

Comment: Отпишите в тегерамм пожалуйста, не совсем понимаю функцию в функции.

Comment: xxx_w1tnessbtw_xxx

Comment: @Леша чуть изменил ответ, может так будет понятней

Comment: Все, понял. Спасибо!

Comment: @Леша так а работает хоть?) Если ответ помог отметьте как правильный.

Comment: Отмечу если работает

Comment: Не работает. disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Expected int parameter, received str instead.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Леша изменил ответ